# Доступ к файлам с использованием хэш-функции

Tags: c#, хеширование

Привет.

Есть одно задание: организовать прямой метод доступа к записям файла для обработки с использованием хеш-функции.

> Реализовать программу  прямого метода доступа к записям в файле для обработки. Файл представляет собой набор данных с прямой организацией (блок - 512 байт) и состоит из записей постоянной длины N байт, максимальное  количество записей  в файле  - M.  Ключ каждой записи -  набор T  символов. Адресом записи является номер блока в файле и  смещение в  блоке.  Тип  адресной  функции  (хеш-функции) выбирается самостоятельно. 
> Предусмотреть следующие операции над файлом: создание файла с заданным именем, его удаление, поиск записи по ключу, ее модификация и удаление.

Собственно, хотелось бы услышать, как должна выбираться здесь хеш-функция, какой она должна быть, и неплохо бы увидеть несколько вариантов. Насколько я понимаю, они все выбираются из пространства имен System.Security.Cryptography?

Comment: Скорее всего речь идёт об организации [хэш-таблицы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0).

Answer (score 1):

Простая функция для строк.

```
h = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    h = 31 * h + str[i];
}
```

len подлежащая хэшированию длина строки по адресу str.

Используется очень давно и в разных местах. В т.ч. в Java.

Comment: h = unchecked(31 * h + str[i]);
    

Так надёжнее, т.к. можно изменить параметры компиляции так, что будут генерироваться проверки на переполнение.

Comment: @AlexeyM, вообще-то при вычислении хэш кода переполнение абсолютно не мешает. Одна из задач, ставящихся перед такими функциями это высокая скорость работы. Проверка на переполнение явно входит в противоречие с ней. 

И еще, как Вы хотите обрабатывать переполнение ?

Comment: @avp, дело в том, что ключ компилятора `csc /checked+` заставит его генерировать проверки на переполнение (т.е. если ясно не указать `unchecked` и скомпилировать с данным ключом, то вышеприведённый код может бросить `System.OverflowException`). Поэтому рекомендуется явно указывать на отсутствие проверок переполнения.

Comment: Ну, да, это же c#.