# Посоветуйте хорошую хеш-функцию

Tags: хеширование, c++

Для хеширования строк.

Comment: варианты можно предлагать в зависимости от нужного уровня безопасности:  
1. защищаемся от школьников  
2. защищаемся от любителей  
3. защищаемся от профи

Comment: Мы не защищаемся, мы ищем:)

Comment: ну ищете вы для какой-то цели или просто так? вопрос ведь тоже задаете с целью получить ответ, или просто так?

Comment: ищу с целью получения денег, как это ни странно :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Недавно отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93777/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

**Перенесено из комментария**.

@pol500, боюсь, Вы что-то **недопонимаете в хэшировании**. Объем хэшированного словаря **всегда больше** исходного.

Ведь Вам необходимо кроме самих ключей (слов из словаря) хранить ссылки на них (организованные в хэш таблицу).

Конечно, для заранее заданного множества ключей можно *попытаться* сделать хэш функцию, исключающую коллизии и в таком случае не хранить сами ключи (слова). Однако, добавление любого нового ключа влечет за собой необходимость тщательного тестирования и возможно подбора новой функции.

Насколько мне известно, на практике так никогда не поступают.

**UPD 2**

Простая программка проверки хэшкода для русских (думаю любых) слов.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// try hash h = h * 31 +str[i]

int
hash (char *s)
{
  int h = 0;
  while (*s) 
    h = h*31+*s++;
  return h;
}

main ()
{
  // make dictionary
  unsigned char str[10000];
  FILE *dict = fopen("dict","w");
  int  nwi = 0, nwo = 0;

  while (scanf("%s",str) == 1) {
    nwi++;
    if (str[0] >= 'A') {
      nwo++;
      fprintf (dict,"%s\n",str);
    }
  }
  fclose(dict);
  printf ("raw dict %d of %d\n",nwo,nwi);
  dict = popen("sort -u dict","r");
  FILE *hf = fopen("hashcodes","w");
  int nwu = 0;
  while (fscanf(dict,"%s",str) == 1) {
    nwu++;
    fprintf (hf,"%d\n", hash(str));
  }
  pclose(dict);
  fclose(hf);
  printf ("%d unic words\nunic hashcodes ",nwu); fflush(stdout);
  system ("sort -u hashcodes | wc -w");
}
```

Comment: да, я помню, и именно по вашему совету я и реализовал свою хеш-функцию. но она не подошла - словарь генерируется почти из всего объема словаря, хотя предыдущая версия моей программы генерила выходные словари процентов на 50 меньшие. Видать то ли хэши повторяются, то ли еще что.

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: Кстати, та функция, что вы советовали ранее, генерирует только 403 уникальных ключа на диапазоне из 9970 слов

Comment: @pol500, Вы меня просто заинтриговали. Написал программку, проверил на "Космической Одиссеи" (первое, что попалось с русскими буквами) 

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out <sp
    raw dict 52370 of 53838
    19288 unic words
    unic hashcodes 19282
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 

Кладу ее (программку) в **UPD 2**. 

Проверьте у себя и отпишите, пожалуйста, о результате.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую хэш функцию [Whirlpool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool_(cryptography)). Хорош тем, что во первых он принадлежит семейству SHA-2 и рекомендован [NIST](http://www.nist.gov/index.html), во вторых алгоритм находится в public domain, в третьих есть сишные (и Java) исходники, ну и в оконцове не так заезжен как MD5 иже с ними.

Comment: Это же криптографический хэш...

Comment: Ну да, а камрад не указал чего он хотел то...

Comment: Ему надо быстро искать русские слова в словаре. [Тут](http://hashcode.ru/questions/94121/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) раньше было обсуждение его проблемы.

Comment: Я думаю, что а) это приступ предварительной оптимизации б) пора уже писать кот в) Jenkins is fine too и г) при корпусе в 15к слов результат от изысканий самого-самого алгоритма будет ничтожно мал.

Answer (score 0):

В 2015 году это [xxHash](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash), [есть реализации на всех популярных языках](https://code.google.com/p/xxhash/).